# saving .txt securely on a device

Tags: ios, security, writetofile

How does one securely save .txt file into ios device? I don't want the user to manipulate it with tools such as iExplorer or similar.
My code so far is just basic data writing in ApplicationSupportDirectry and it look like this:

///writing to file:

```
do{
try stringFile.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

}catch{}
```

Comment: You can encrypt the data rather easily using a 3rd party library such as the well regarded and vetted [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypt it when creating / updating the file, decrypt it when reading the file. [Store the encryption key in the keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3) and you'll be safer than plaintext.
[Documentation about symmetric encryption which is available to iOS and OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCCryptor.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CCCryptor).

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. Can you be a little more specific? Which Apple framework is suitable for this task?

Comment: And not to mention you will need an encryption export license if you intend to submit this to Apple.

Comment: @zaph should now reference symmetric encryption. I was not aware that the "Encryption in iOS" section I was referencing before was only documenting asymmetric encryption.

Comment: The Answer is more like a comment, mainly two links, than an answer but at least it is not incorrect.

Comment: Re: encryption export license. If there is no major concern about the encryption security you can use DES (Data Encryption Standard) which has a key length of 56-bits and only requires a notification send
the government (BIS) a "NOTIFICATION", and upload a copy of
this to Apple. Note: DES is no longer considered secure but may meet the OP's needs.

Comment: @trojanfoe Since 2010 all that is needed is an ERN (Encryption Registration Number) See [THE LANE FILES](http://tigelane.blogspot.com/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html) for a writeup on the process.

Comment: @zaph Hey thanks for that.  I was considering using a hash to detect fiddling with my (game) preferences, but encryption is better still.

Comment: @zaph Unfortunately the link, within the link you posted, is now stale, and contains the vital steps 1 and 2.  Any idea of an updated link?

Comment: Ah found the [update link](https://www.zetetic.net/blog/2009/8/3/mass-market-encryption-ccats-commodity-classification-for-ip.html).

Comment: @trojanfoe beat me to the new link. It is not clear if the time to obtain SNAP-R PIN has gotten better.

Comment: It accepted my (UK) address for step 1, which is better than some of the replies in the blog you posted, so it's looking better...